Raspberry pi 4 and ev3
I'm working on a project, I want to use computer vision on the Raspberry Pi 4 to identify objects and then send the information to the ev3. For this communication, I want to know if there is any way to make it via connection using cables or Bluetooth

what's an ev3? ... please update your post with info
